# How to dynamically set JSON field name in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

**JSON received from API.**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "timestamp": 1645988822,
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2022-02-27",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 4.140586,
    "AFN": 102.662987,
    "ALL": 121.380824,
    "AMD": 538.7856,
    "ANG": 2.016644,
    "AOA": 559.803561
  }
}
```

**I am parsing JSON through this way in data weave expression but it gives error**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "Result":
    {
        "Data":payload.rates.{Currency}        // Currency=AED  
    }
}
```

**Desired JSON output should be as follow**

```
{
    "Result":
    {
        "Data":4.140586
    }
}
```

Comment: The example output includes incorrectly a DataWeave script. I'll edit to fix it and the rest of the format. Please read the formatting help for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an incorrect syntax. `payload.rates` is an object so you can just use the [dynamic selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors#dynamic_selector):

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var selectedCurrency="AED"
---
{
    "Result":
    {
        "Data": payload.rates[selectedCurrency]
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Result": {
    "Data": 4.140586
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Your solution solved my problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

Input:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "timestamp": 1645988822,
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2022-02-27",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 4.140586,
    "AFN": 102.662987,
    "ALL": 121.380824,
    "AMD": 538.7856,
    "ANG": 2.016644,
    "AOA": 559.803561
  }
}
```

Dataweave

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "Result":
    {
        "Data":payload.rates.AED        
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Result": {
    "Data": 4.140586
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't solve my problem.